# How to freeze frame with css

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a table with a scrollable body. I'll have my header row, then the data that will scroll while the header is fixed. This is kind of like freezing panes in excel. I tried creating a table above the content I want to scroll, but the column widths don't match up. It looks to me that everything has to be in one table for all the columns to match up. What's the best way to do this?

I set up a fiddle to show what I'm trying to do. I tried a whole bunch of things to make this work, but never got it to come out right.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/polyhedron/pzbmS/2/

Comment: I'm getting a little closer, but I can't get everything to line up just right. 
http://www.jsfiddle.net/polyhedron/pzbmS/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to look fine to me - assuming that I understand you correctly.

Edit : Sorry - I am sure you looking for an alternatives. These might help

[Pure CSS Scrollable Tables](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html)

[Another similar link...](http://geekswithblogs.net/LSheu/archive/2009/01/30/css-table-scrolling-with-fixed-header-for-ie-7.aspx)

Here's a quick and dirty jsFiddle I made - it only uses 1 row as you mentioned.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BECRS/1/)

Comment: in this case (just for example) i want a window that is only 35px tall with a scroll bar on the side. The scroll bar will only scroll the product information, but not the header.

Comment: So that you could only see a single row at a time? Or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I had a project where I needed the same behavior. Here is what I came up with:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/01/html-scrolling-table-with-fixed-headers-jquery-plugin/

Here is a demo page of the end result:

http://bobcravens.com/demos/FixedHeaderTable/index.html

Hope this gets you started. Let me know if you have questions.

Bob

Answer (score -1):

Add a text-align: left to thead tr element:

```
thead tr
{
 text-align: left;
}
```